# why it is possible to pass the undeclared function to setTimeout

Tags: javascript, callback, async.js

Here is the code example from Trevor Burnham's "Async JavaScript" book (The Pragmatic Bookshelf, 2012):

```
var async = require ('async');

var start = new Date;

async.series([
  function(callback) { setTimeout(callback, 100); },
  function(callback) { setTimeout(callback, 300); },
  function(callback) { setTimeout(callback, 200); }
], function(err, results) {
  // show time elapsed since start
  console.log('Completed in ' + (new Date - start) + 'ms');
});
```

It just puzzles me why is it possible to schedule the undeclared "callback" function using setTimeout? The code executes OK in node, but what exactly does it do? Whether the calls for "callback" are really scheduled for execution at the specified points in time and did they really execute?

Comment: Well, what? `async` and `.series`?

Comment: Yes, async.series. Here is the documentation: (https://github.com/caolan/async#seriestasks-callback).

Comment: Uh, `callback` is clearly declared as a parameter in every of these functions?

Answer (score 1):

`callback` isn't undeclared, it's passed as argument into the anonymous function, right here:

```
function(callback) { setTimeout(callback, 100); }
         ^^^^^^^^               ^^^^^^^^
            |                      |
            +----------------------+
```

It's provided by whoever actually executes the anonymous function. [The documentation for `async.series`](https://github.com/caolan/async#seriestasks-callback) says:

> `tasks` - A collection containing functions to run, **each function is passed a `callback(err, result)`** it must call on completion with an error `err` (which can be `null`) and an optional `result` value.

Answer (score 1):

Yes `callback` is defined, but not in your script. It is defined in `async` module's [source](https://github.com/caolan/async/blob/master/lib/iterator.js) code:

```
'use strict';

export default function(tasks) {
    function makeCallback(index) {
        function fn() {
            if (tasks.length) {
                tasks[index].apply(null, arguments);
            }
            return fn.next();
        }
        fn.next = function() {
            return (index < tasks.length - 1) ? makeCallback(index + 1) : null;
        };
        return fn;
    }
    return makeCallback(0);
}
```

`async` module defines a function and passes it as `callback` parameter to every function in series.

Comment: I believe your answer is quite close to the truth, but I do not see the arguments parsing in the function that is returned from makeCallback(). According to the docs, the callback function must steer either to passing its first argument (error) to the "completionCallback" parameter of async.series(), or otherwise to the next task execution.